# Solving $\lim_{t \to \infty} t\log(\frac{\frac{\log(\alpha + 1)}{t} - \frac{\log(t + \alpha)}{t}}{ 1 - \frac{1}{t(t + \alpha)}} + 1)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Given the following problem

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split} {\label{limit}}
\lim_{t \to \infty} t\log\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\log(\alpha + 1)}{t} - \dfrac{\log(t + \alpha)}{t}}{ 1 - \dfrac{1}{t(t + \alpha)}} + 1\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

where $t \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\alpha > 0$ how can I compute such a limit?

Edit:
I had forgetten the + 1 inside the log in the original question. I added it.

Comment: @GEdgar: The limit is basically $$t\ln(1-(\ln t)/t) $$so that the "+1" **does** fix the argument of the outer log..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(...new answer because the question was edited to yield a different result)

Assuming $\log=\ln$, it's
$$L=\lim_{t\to\infty} t \ln a_t$$ $\def\a{\alpha}$
where
$$\begin{align}
a_t
&= 1+\frac{\dfrac{\ln(\alpha + 1)}{t} - \dfrac{\ln(t + \alpha)}{t}}{ 1 - \dfrac{1}{t(t + \alpha)}} \\
&= 1-\frac{\ln\dfrac{t+\a}{\a+1}}{t-\dfrac{1}{t+\alpha}} =:1-x(t)\\
\end{align}$$
Hence $a_t\to 1$ and we can use the expansion of $\ln$ at 1 which is:

$$\ln(1-x)=-x+\Theta(x^2) \quad\text{ for }|x|<1$$

provided $t$ is large enough, and where $\Theta$ denotes a Landau symbol:

$$\begin{align}
t\ln a_t 
&= t\ln(1-x) \\
&= -t(x+\Theta(x^2)) \\
&= -\frac{\ln\dfrac{t+\a}{\a+1}}{1-\dfrac{1}{t(t+\a)}} + \Theta (tx^2)\\
&\to-\infty
\end{align}$$
and where the error term is of order $(\ln^2t)/t$.

Comment: Great thank you! I think you missed a negative sign though, it should be $-\infty$

Comment: @zsheeba: oops, I'll fix it.